# Does apache-storm provide priority mailbox like akka does

Tags: akka, apache-storm

As it is explained in [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java/mailboxes.html#prioritymailbox), akka provides priority mailboxes which helps if you want to process some type of message before other types. I didn't found similar feature in storm documentation, is there similar support available in apache-storm or how can similar behaviour be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

No, Storm doesn't have anything like this as far as I'm aware. Messages are processed in the order they arrive at the bolts.

If you really need this functionality, the nicest way to get this effect might be to submit your topology twice in two configurations; one that reads low priority messages and one that reads only high priority messages. While you could partition the tuple stream into low and high priority messages in one topology, you might still see some interference from low priority messages on e.g. `topology.max.spout.pending`.